# One DAO per Database Connection?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Using Spring and JDBCTemplates (no ORM), I have a DAO that goes against a CMS database.

I now have a need to access another database.  Should I create a separate DAO or use one big DAO?  Either seems to work in my case.  I have an interface, but it is not a generic interface.  Except for an INSERT into an audit table, all I do is retrieve values.  So I don't feel I need a separate CRUD service for each table, per this [link](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/generic_crud_service_aka_dao)

I don't think it really matters, but one database is MySQL, the other is Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read about the DAO pattern by Googling but, in general, you create one DAO for each 'table' or group of related tables. I don't know if that's what you mean by 'database'. Some people use the terms that way. (You updated your question to explain 'database'. So you would typically have multiple DAOs per database with one per table or set of related tables.)

So "Yes"

NOTE: When I say 'related tables' I may need to explain. For example, if you have an invoice table and a invoice_detail table. The detail rows would typically be like a line on a paper invoice and have a foreign key back to the invoice id or invoice number in the invoice table. There are two tables but you would probably have a single DAO to deal with invoices and the details associated with them. There might be methods to get an invoice by invoice number and by customer and a bunch of them by date and maybe also to get all invoices during a month that have a particular item on one of their detail lines. There would be methods to create an invoice and create all the lines on it. And so forth. One DAO but multiple tables.

The details lines might have foreign keys pointing over to a 'parts' table with details on the parts. You might want to read the parts info and return it with the invoice and you might want to just read parts separately after you read the invoice. In the latter case, there would be a 2nd DAO that has methods to read and, possibly, modify the parts records.

This example assumes these are all in the same database, be it MySQL or Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You should be injecting a `DataSource` into your DAOs that you in turn use to create your `SimpleJdbcTemplate`. Since a `DataSource` connects to a specific database, it follows that you will need separate DAOs/`DataSource`s/`SimpleJdbcTemplate`s for each of your databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple "DAO" per table or data entity in your Spring application, but you still should segregate your database calls plus Spring needs to know the distinct connection parameters and that can be separated using the DAO definitions in the applicationContext.  This sounds like a candidate for a REST Web Service to handle your retrievals from the other database.